# General formula for the number of non-decreasing numbers with d digits, lower than X

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Follow up from this post: [Count the number of non-decreasing numbers with d digits, lower than X](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532735/count-the-number-of-non-decreasing-numbers-with-d-digits-lower-than-x), which gives an example of working out the number of non-decreasing four-digit numbers less than 5000.

I'm looking for a general formula for any value X, where X is a d-digit number. The number of non-decreasing d-digit numbers is given by $${9+d \choose d}$$ and then by considering the number of non-decreasing numbers below X, we subtract the number of non-decreasing d-digit numbers greater than X from the above, which is given by another binomial coefficient expression which I'm struggling to work out.

I suspect it is related to the first digit of X, denoted $X_0$: $${9+d-(X_0) \choose 9-(X_0)}$$ but any help would be much appreciated.